# Game where you adjoin 成语

Tags: proverb

I am thinking of writing a game where you adjoin 成语.

The one where each proverb is four characters long and people play in a round robin fashion or against the computer (this seems the only way to design a game where there is no cheating, because if users played using their phones over the network then they could just look up stuff in a dictionary (this way，cheating).

I was wondering, not only what the game is called, but what are some of the challenges of the game, besides, remembering, thus, from a psychological rather than mnemocnic standpoint.

I wonder whether one goes though an emotional rollercoaster, even if they know all 成语 very well during this game. How does one deal with this sort of challenge?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're referring to 成语接龙. I don't quite get the part about cheating. Why does playing against a computer prevents people from looking up dictionaries? There's lots of paper dictionaries.

Comment: I used to play this game. To make the chains reasonably lengthy, we accepted Homophones. For example, When we have一舉成名 followed by 名成利就， the chain would end with 就 because there is no idiom starting with 就, by accepting Homophones, you can go  一舉成名，名成利就，袖手旁觀，官官相衛，為民請命，命不久矣，以逸待勞，勞苦功高，高朋滿座，座無虛席，直斥其非，飛瑝騰達，達者為先，先聲奪人，人心惶惶，黃雀在後，後來居上，上下其手，手足情深，深藏不露，路不拾遺，遺愛人間，奸夫淫婦，婦人之仁，仁至義盡，盡忠職守，守望相助，助人為樂，樂不思蜀 (It is a Cantonese chain)

Comment: It's like solving some 奇妙的 maths problems

Answer (score 0):

I think if you write a computer program for this game, just make sure it accepts multiple correct answers,  since many chengyu share characters and people will think of different possibilities to finish a set.

Also, you may want to be laxer on the meaning of "chengyu".  Exactly what counts as a chengyu depends on how strictly you define it.  Many people consider things chengyu that might not  strictly define as such, like the halves of other types of chinese sayings/proverbs or general sayings/phrases ( ◠‿◠ )